# Two subsequences converge then sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose I have a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ and I'm trying to show it converges. If we assume that I've shown the subsequences $\{a_{2n}\}$ and $\{a_{2n+1}\}$ both converge to $A$ then can we say that $\{a_{n}\}\to A$?

I believe that we can say this, but only in the case that the union of the subsequences gives $\mathbb{N}$? So since we the subsequences are the odd and even terms this holds.

However I'm not sure how to prove the result.

Attempt:

Given $\{a_{2n}\} \to A$ then $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_{1}, |a_{2n} - A| < \epsilon, n > N_{1}$.

Similarly for $\{a_{2n+1}\}$ $ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_{2}, |a_{2n+1} - A| < \epsilon, n > N_{2}$.

Now if I let $ N = \max\{N_{1}, N_{2}\}$ then for $n > N$ I guess the result follows. BUT if so I don't quite see why. Since what I'm taking the max of applies to subsequences.

Comment: $n > \max(N_1,N_2)$ is either odd or even and therefore...

Comment: Then for $n \ge N$  $|a_n-A|<\epsilon$. n=2k (even)OK, n=2k+1 also OK.

Comment: Thanks both, so obvious! Thanks!

Comment: "*...we can say this, but only in the case that the union of the subsequences gives $\Bbb N$?*"  Quite right.  As an example, $(0,\frac{1}{2},3,0,\frac{1}{5},6,0,\frac{1}{8},9,0,\frac{1}{11},12,\dots)$ has the subsequences $a_{3k+1}$ (*which is constantly zero*) and $a_{3k+2}$ (*which is $\frac{1}{3k+2}$*) both converging to $0$ but the overall sequence clearly does not and fails to be bounded thanks to the $a_{3k}$ terms.